# Using Text data type in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using Mysql with INNODB Engine and the row_format is Barracuda.

Now I have a table which has a PK column and lots of(about one hundred and eighty) columns with Text data type.

My question is If the table's data get large what will the main performance issue or any disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just store data in those TEXT columns - it's acceptable. If you have indexes on those columns - use dictionary encoding for them.

Comment: The PK is INT. What do you mean by use dictionary encoding for them. What's dictionary encoding? How can I do that?

Comment: Dictionary encoding is using a dictionary table, where you store your text data and using in other tables it's integer id for most of operations. You can also create a VIEW if you when you need to work with actual text data.

You don't need dictionary encoding if you don't plan to use indexes on those TEXT fields.